# Database Connection does not release after idle time out in glassfish

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

i am using **Glassfish 3 & mysql5.6.11.**

i have created `JDBC connection pool in glassfish`.

```
Initial and Minimum Pool Size: - 8
Maximum Pool Size: -30
Pool Resize Quantity:- 10
Idle Timeout: - 60 (second).
Max Wait Time:- 2500 (millisecond).
```

with this parameter i have **created pool setting**.

i have **set pool resize quantity value**.

when no of connections increase, it does not release after idle time-out.
next time when i hit url it again increase no of connection, it does not reuse already open connection.

i am getting exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.
```

i am using show processlist in mysql to show open connection.

if any one knows the solution of this problem, please share your idea with me.

i need help from any one.

Answer (score 1):

Idle timeout is just the time that unused connections in the pool will remain in the pool before they are closed/recycled. That problem you are having is most likely that you are not closing your connections after use.

Fix your code to close connections when you are done with them, closing a connection will release it back to the connection pool so they are available for reuse.

Some connection pools have additional timeouts for the time a connection can be used, forcing the connection back in the pool after that time. Which to the user of that connection will look as if the connection has been closed. I don't think the glassfish pool has this option though.

Comment: i have written code for closing connection.It only happens with application deployed in glassfish.Its working fine with POJO class.