# JDBC connection pools in glassfish server

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I have configured a JDBC pool in Glassfish server.

```
Max pool size=500 , Steady pool size=100 , pool resize quantity=8, idle-time-out-in-seconds=300 .
```

After doing more research I came to know that after *idel-time-out-in-seconds some inactive sessions(pool resize quantity) are removed from the pool if the size of the pool is more than steady pool size.*

Suppose now the server is started and the pool has 100 connections and there are no request to server, in this case the connections would become idle but as the size of the pool is 100 same as steady pool sessions , **will the inactive sessions never removed from the pool ?**

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose now the server is started and the pool has 100 connections and
>   there are no request to server, in this case the connections would
>   become idle but as the size of the pool is 100 same as steady pool
>   sessions, will the inactive sessions never removed from the pool?

The inactive connections will get removed from the pool, but they will be recreated to ensure the minimum number of connections in the pool (indicated by the steady-pool-size setting) will be available.

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24936/tuning-glassfish.htm):

> Idle Timeout: Maximum time in seconds that a connection can remain
>   idle in the pool. After this time, the pool can close this connection.
>   This property does not control connection timeouts on the database
>   server.

To make sure you can activate Monitoring for the JDBC Connection Pool. To do this open the Glassfish Admin UI and navigate to `server-config` -> `Monitoring`. Enable the Monitoring Service and set the Level for "JDBC Connection Pool" to HIGH. Then navigate to  `server` (the second item in the upper left menu of the Glassfish Admin UI) -> `Monitor` -> `Resources` and select your connection pool. You can see how many connection have been opened, closed, released and timed out.

**See also:**

- [Database Connection does not release after idle time out in glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683504/database-connection-does-not-release-after-idle-time-out-in-glassfish)